# Textfile to array transfer

Tags: c++

Can someone help me out with a for loop that can read from a text file and output that to an array?

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCreatures[x]; i++)
    {
        dataFile = creaturesDT[i];
    }
```

kind of what I'm thinking, this is wrong though.

Comment: What this dataFile means

Comment: Read about [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). With these all you need is three lines to read a complete file.

Comment: We broached those in the last few minutes of class today, and the teacher sucked at explaining them so im attempting to decrypt the book now. ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you could write:

```
// Input stream for your file. Passing the file name and it gets open for you
ifstream dataFile("test.txt");

// Array replacement with a proper container
vector<string> stringlist;

// Temporary variable to read the line or word in
string mystring;

// Read continously into the temporary variable until you run out of data
while (getline(dataFile, mystring)) {
    // In each iteration, push the value of the temporary variable
    // to the end of the container
    stringlist.push_back(mystring);
}

// At last, close the file as we do not need it anymore
dataFile.close();
```

I suggest not to use raw arrays for this, but proper standard library containers such as `vector` or `list` and `string`. It also depends on your exact use case whether you wish to use the `operator>>` overload, or getline. The former will read a word, whereas the latter will read a line in.

Comment: Can you explain how these lines of code work, i just started working with files and they are devouring me. and i can use a standard array, ive got a nested structure that im supposed to use.

Comment: Thank you!! ill try and see if something like this can be fitted to my needs!

Comment: Question though with this i wouldn't even need the for loop to increment the lines right?

Comment: Well i though i would because in the structure i have 10 (think they are called operators) and in the file that im reading from said line are separated by '#' so its supposed to know when to just to the new 'operator'